# I can't figure out why the input is not updating using MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

So I tried to use MobX with react but I can't figure out why the input doesn't have its value updated.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
@observer(['recipeStore'])
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.props.recipeStore.og} onChange={(e) => {this.props.recipeStore.og = e.target.value}}/>
    );
  }
}

class RecipeStore {
  @observable og;
  @observable style;

  constructor() {
    this.og = 1;
    this.style = {og_low: 1, og_high: 1, fg_low: 1, fg_high: 1, abv_low: 1, abv_high: 1};
  }

  @computed get fg() {
    if (!this.og) return '';
    return (((this.og - 1) * 0.25) + 1).toFixed(3);
  }

  @computed get abv() {
    if (!this.og) return '';
    return ((this.og - this.fg) * 131).toFixed(1);
  }
}

const recipeStore = new RecipeStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider recipeStore={recipeStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsbin.com/wuvutagewu/1/edit?js,console,output). Write `recipeStore.og` in the console and you will see that the value is updated. Try to show all relevant code in the question instead of linking to an external resource.

Comment: I'm going to review the code later and try to find the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I refactored my code to have the minimum as possible, like you did in JS bin, I can confirm that RecipeStore is receiving updates, but the React component lifecycle isn't being triggered after onChange event. Even the shouldComponentUpdate doesn't run. That's weird.

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate will not run for updates scheduled by MobX, as it won't allow you to cancel an update and introduce an inconsistent component. (it will run for prop changes and setState calls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Because I saw that my store was being updated but none of the react components lifecycle were being triggered I had to look in other places.

Turns out the problem was that the `@observer` decorator was not properly working.

I had to change my `babel.dev.js` to make sure the plugin `'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy'` was the first in the list.

I found the hint here: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/105#issuecomment-213356342