# React / MobX: Store values are undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

My MobX autorun function logs out `undefined` for both of the values here. Also, in my components that `import user from '../../stores/UserStore`, the instances that I use `{user.userName}` all show nothing at all.

```
import { observable, autorun } from 'mobx'

class UserStore {
  @observable userName = "tommy";
  @observable arr = [0,1]
}

const user = window.user = new UserStore

export default user;


// user.userName = "timmy"; // works, but not observable.

autorun(() => {
  console.log(user.userName) // undefined
  console.log(user.arr) // undefined
})
```

Comment: did you mean `new UserStore()` ?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsbin.com/jumipucalo/edit?js,console). Try changing the fields of `user` in the console. Maybe you are running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381706/i-cant-figure-out-why-the-input-is-not-updating-using-mobx)?

Comment: I came to find that the problem had to do with my usage of `create-react-app`. I was able to get the observer/observable functions to work, but without decorators.

`observer(export default class MyComponent extends Component { ...`
and
`class MyStore { myValue = observable('some value here') }`

Comment: Do decorators in general not work for you? You may have to manually install the Babel plugin for it

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use decorators with create-react-app you will need to eject the app. "*Running npm run eject copies all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies.*" https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app Also I found you need to put transform-decorators-legacy plugin first like so:

```
plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy','transform-class-properties']
```

After you do all this. The following will work and has been tested.

```
@observer class Counter extends React.Component {
    @observable count = 0
}
```

Comment: Underrated answer. Thanks for the tip of putting the decorator plugin first.

Comment: Putting `transform-decorators-legacy` in the beginning solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just moving the following to the top of the plugins array in the `babel.config.js` file solved the problem for me.

```js
["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
```